# Is there any Nativescript Jalali Calendar plugin ? (or how can i feed Persian(Jalali) Date to RadCalendar to show?)

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I need to use Jalali Calendar in my cross platfrom application and using Nativesript framework to do that but I couldnt find any Persian ( Jalali ) Calendar plugin inside https://market.nativescript.org/ (where all the Nativescript plugins and samples and templates are there !) and I couldn't use the RadCalendar ( the calendar plugin of NS) with the Persian (Jalali ) Date ! It shows me only gregorian date.

Comment: Try setting the [locale](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/Calendar/localization#defining-locales-on-radcalendar) property to your desired value.

Comment: @Manoj It's just setting the Month Names and other Labels to Persian ( Not the Calendar Type ) the calendar is still in Gregorian !